# How to make a navbar menu block on mobile invisible ? (responsiveness)

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, responsiveness

I am having this problem while coding a responsive website, that the menu block of the navbar is shown if you scroll to the right, but I only want it to appear if i click on the menu icon.

What should i change about the code snippet so the menu block will only be visible if i click on the icon

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-200px"
}
```

```css
@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #194641;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="../properties/logo.svg"></a>
  <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
    <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CAREER</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
</nav>
```

I would be grateful for any leads!

Actually I've just set the right property for the nav-links block to -200px, so you can't see it when the page is loaded. But if you swipe to the right the navbar is still visible.